# Django: difference between is_valid and form_valid

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I've created a form which is a `forms.ModelForm`. On the "view" side, I've created a view which is a `generic.UpdateView`.

In those 2 differents classes, I have `is_valid()` on one side, and `form_valid()` on the other side.

```
class ProfileForm(FormForceLocalizedDateFields):

    class Meta:
        model = Personne
        fields = ('sexe', 'statut', 'est_fumeur',
                  'est_physique', 'date_naissance')
        exclude = ('user', 'est_physique')

    # blabla fields declaration

    def is_valid(self):
        pass
```

and edit view:

```
class EditView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = Personne
    template_name = 'my_home/profile/edit.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('my_home_index')

    # blabla get_initial() and get_object() and get_context_data()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        # Hack: redirect on same URL:
        # - if user refreshes, no form re-send
        # - if user goes back, no form re-send too, classical refresh
        site_web = u"{0}://{1}".format(
            self.request.scheme, self.request.META['HTTP_HOST']
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(u'{0}{1}'.format(
            site_web, self.request.META['PATH_INFO']
        ))
```

My form shows 3 fields of 3 different models :

- `User`,
- `Person` which has a foreign key to User
- `Picture` which has a foreign key to `Person`

Where should I create the code that update those fields, and why?

`generic.UpdateView` is supposed to help us when updating fields, but it seems that when you have fields not belonging to the `model` you edit, you have to write **all** the "update" by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is_valid` on the surface just tells you whether or not the form is valid, and thats the only job it should ever do..

From the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L156):

```
def is_valid(self):

    """
    Returns True if the form has no errors. Otherwise, False. If errors are
    being ignored, returns False.
    """
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
```

Underneath this, what it also does is (from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid))

> run validation and return a boolean designating whether the data was valid:

The validation is ran because `errors` is a property that will call `full_clean` if the validation hasn't been called yet.

```
 @property
 def errors(self):

    "Returns an ErrorDict for the data provided for the form"
    if self._errors is None:
        self.full_clean()
    return self._errors
```

> Where should I create the code that update those fields, and why?

In the `form_valid` method because by this point you've found out that your validation has verified that it is safe to update your model.

Comment: @OlivierPons - No worries, enjoy!

Comment: @OlivierPons - Its a bit tricky and it may require a new question to get an answer... I'd look into validating the file before you ever save it somewhere, assuming you are using temporary file storage as per django default uploads

Comment: I was adding my question while you were answering.. **`:^D`** There we go **`>>`** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397856/django-how-to-handle-valid-files-in-is-valid-or-form-valid