# Show error in templates django

Tags: django, django-templates

im using the form.add_error option of django to add customized errors to

form checks.

when i use the add_error in the ModelForm the errors are shown in the

template, but when i use it in the view it doesn't..

what might be the problem?

the modelform add_error (in the clean method):

```
self.add_error('field', "fdgdsfgfds.")
```

the view add_error:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.add_error('field', "sfsfdsfsd.")
    return self.form_invalid(form)
```

in the template:

```
{{ form.errors }}
{{ field.errors }}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
{{ form.as_table }}
```

Comment: You can't use it in form valid method

Comment: do you know what can i use in form_valid to customize checks?

Comment: in the documentation it say: "This method allows adding errors to specific fields from within the Form.clean() method, or from outside the form altogether; for instance from a view." - so i can use it the the view.. but if not in the form_valid than where?

Comment: Form valid method is called *after* all your validation steps have been done so adding errors there doesn't make sense what's wrong with doing it in the clean methods? (I'd write an answer but I'm on my phone)

Comment: actually don't know why i didn't do it from the clean method.. but i will appreciate if you will write an answer when you will have time

Comment: Sure I will take a look later when I get chance to go on computer. But basically use your clean methods to validate.

Answer (score 2):

Django model forms have a certain way of working and this in essence is a good thing because it makes sure your code stays clean and that each one of your methods have a standardized flow control.

The forms `clean` and `clean_fieldname` methods should be where all of your validation is done, these methods get called from the forms `is_valid` method and all contribute with their errors towards statings whether the form is valid or not. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34392420/1324033) for a more detailed explanation as to how `is_valid` actually calls the clean methods

The `form_valid` and `form_invalid` are for you to handle in your view to handle what response should be shown. The django generic views by default will render `success_url` if the form is valid although you may find you want to override these methods to return a `JsonResponse` or similar to make your form more ajaxxy.

So any time you want to report errors, you need to use your clean methods. You may find in the future that you want to reuse a form and you don't want to repeat yourself in views by having to do validation again, so keeping all the validation contained in the form makes this possible. The views job is to handle where you want to display your form and what other context it would need.